# What is the period of $f(X) = (A+K\cdot X) \mod N$

Tags: number-theory, modular-arithmetic, periodic-functions

I have a function $f$ mapping from integers to integers as follows:

$f(X) = (A+K \cdot X) \mod N$

Where $A,K,X,N$ are positive integers.

What is the period of the function?

Comment: First hint:  does the value of $A$ affect the period?

Answer (score 1):

We want $p$ minimal so that $f(x)=f(x+p)$.  Hence $$a+kx\equiv a+k(x+p)\pmod{n}$$
We subtract $a$ from each side, then $kx$, to get $$0\equiv kp\pmod{n}$$

Comment: Is p equal to lcm(n,k)/k?